# Path Variable Windows 10 - Python not found

Tags: windows, path

I installed python38 in

```
c:\Dev\python38
```

Added the following to my path variable:

```
C:\Dev\python38;C:\Dev\python38\Scripts
```

So my path variable now is:

```
C:\Dev\python38;C:\Dev\python38\Scripts;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

When I invoke python or pip on a command prompt, I get
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command ...

When I echo the path variable I get

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Symantec.cloud\PlatformAgent\;"C:\Dev\python38;C:\Dev\python38\Scripts;C:\Users\Gym Source\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There should never be quotes in `PATH`: `"C:\Dev\python38;C:\Dev\python38\Scripts;C:\Users\Gym Source\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps";`

Comment: Thanks. In System Properties --> Environment Variables, I am setting the path as C:\Dev\python38;C:\Dev\python38\Scripts;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps      However, Windows is adding the quotes to this as you noted.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the dialog that's displayed when you double click on the user "Path" value in the environment variables editor. If it's correct, in Windows 10 the dialog should be an exploded view with one path entry per line.

Answer (score 0):

@Eryk Sun commented that I had double quotes. That got me looking further. 
I was updating the existing value of path variable by adding additional paths and semicolon. This resulted in quotes being added by Windows.

Instead, I added additional paths in the variable by using the "New" operation which would open a line for a path to be included.